# MVC dropdownlist filter onchange

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an index view with dropdownlist filter. Whenever a new item is selected from the dropdownlist, the index page will display data based on groupid. Here is the view

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("index", "service"))
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="navbar-header" style="margin:10px 0px 5px 5px">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <a id="btnSAdd" class="btn btn-info glyphicon glyphicon-plus" href="/AppName/Service/Create"> Create New </a>
                    <button type="submit" id="btnSSave" class="btn btn-info glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-save">  Save  </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-responsive-collapse" style="margin:10px 0px 5px 5px">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="navbar" style="font-family:'Californian FB';font-weight:bold">Select a Menu:</span>
                        @Html.DropDownList("GroupID", new SelectList(ViewBag.TopMenuList, "GroupID", "GroupName"),
                            new { @class = "btn btn-info dropdown-toggle", @style = "border-color:grainsboro", @onchange = "window.location = 'service/index?groupid=' + this.value" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div id="drag" class="panel-body">
            <table class="table table-hover" style="width:auto" id="sTable">
            <colgroup>
                <col width="30" />
                <col width="250" />
                <col width="250" />
                <col width="200" />
            </colgroup>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>&nbsp;</th>
                    <th>Parent Group</th>
                    <th>Service Name</th>
                    <th>Service Description</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
                {
                    <tr class="orderedrow">
                        <td class="rowhandler">
                            <div class="drag rowdip">@Html.HiddenFor(model => model[i].ServiceID)</div>
                        </td>
                        <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model[i].GroupID, new SelectList(Model[i].ParentServiceGroupList, "GroupID", "GroupName", Model[i].GroupID))</td>
                        <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model[i].ServiceName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @style = "width:250px" } })</td>
                        <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model[i].ServiceDescription, new { htmlAttributes = new { @style = "width:250px" } })</td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
            </table>
        </div><!--End Div drag-->
    </div><!--End of row-->
}
```

RouteConfig.cs

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

The problem I am having is the filter works only the first time as

> http://localhost/AppName/service/index?groupid=4

. The second time, it seems to append my url as

> http://localhost/AppName/service**/service**/index?groupid=5

How do I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Is `AppName` an area? (and you need to stop polluting your markup with behavior and learn to use unobtrusive javascript)

Comment: Hi Stephen, AppName is the project name on VS. What do you mean by stop polluting the markup with behavior? Sorry. I'm an occasional web developer so my experience in web developing is limited.

Comment: [What is unobtrusive javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript). Can you show the contents of your `RouteConfig.cs` file

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this

```
@onchange = "window.location = 'service/index?groupid=' + this.value"
```

to this

```
@onchange = "window.location = '/service/index?groupid=' + this.value"
```

Comment: It would miss the Service controller and give me this http://localhost/AppName/index?groupid=4. If I try @onchange = "window.location = '~/service/index?groupid=' + this.value", it would give me this http://localhost/AppName/~/service/index?groupid=4.

Comment: I tried @onchanged="window.location='/service/index?groupid=' + this.value" and it gave me this localhost/service/index?groupid=4. It took away the AppName